# Comma between two conditional clauses

Tags: conditional-constructions, punctuation

How should I punctuate the following sentece with the given logical structure when I want to use conjuction "if" only one time and a conjuction "and" to seperate the conditions?

Logical structure: [Statement] is true if [Condition #1] and [Condition #2] is true.

> "This method is implemented if it's impossible to verify the results of the process, **and** the shorcomings may not be revealed until the product is used."

Should a comma be between "process" & "and"?

And what if I use a conjuction "or" (with OR logical relation) instead of "and"? How would the presence or lack of a comma would affect the sentence grammarly and logically?

> "This method is implemented if it's impossible to verify the results of the process, **or** the shorcomings may not be revealed until the product is used."

Answer (score 1):

"This method is implemented if it's impossible to verify the results of the process , and the shortcomings may not be revealed until the product is used."

For clarity, an easier-to-read version would be:

"This method is implemented [or used] if verification of process results is impossible and if shortcomings are not revealed until the product is used."

It's best to use subject-verb-predicate in English. In my version, this structure is used even after the If clause with a compound phrases. I suggest two IFs to make sure it is read as two conditions and not a "compound" condition.

This X is Y if A is B or if C is D.

This X is Y if A is B and if C is D.

This X is Y if A is B and C is D.

Conclusion: There is no comma in these sentences.

Comment: You know what is very distressing? To answer a question, then have the OP repeat his/her same question again.

Comment: No comma. How many times do  you want me to repeat it?